# Passing in and returning an Array

Tags: java

I have a class called `MarathonRunner` and a class I use for testing it called `MarathonRunnerTest`.

In the main method in my test class, I create an array call `runners` with 15 person objects in it (each object has a name, last name, address, and time it took them to run the marathon). I then want to pass that array into a method defined in my `MarathonRunner` class called `getFastTestRunner()` that takes an array of type `MarathonRunner`.  That method is then supposed to return the name and address of the runner that ran the marathon in the shortest time.

I'm really stuck on this and not sure which direction to go nor how to implement it.

Should I try to sort the array and then pass it all back, or do I use the method to find the fastest runner and pass back an array object with only the fastest runner in it?

My problem is two-fold.  I'm not sure which strategy I should use and how to implement it.  I'll give you what I got so far.

```
public class BanffMaratonRunnerTest{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BanffMarathonRunner elenaBrandon = new BanffMarathonRunner("Elena", "Brandon", "123 Street", 341, 1);
        BanffMarathonRunner thomasMolson = new BanffMarathonRunner("Thomas", "Molson", "Box 2222", 273, 2);
        BanffMarathonRunner hamiltonWinn = new BanffMarathonRunner("Hamilton", "123 Street", "Winn", 278, 5);
        BanffMarathonRunner suzieSarandin = new BanffMarathonRunner("Suzie", "123 Street", "Sarandin", 329, 7);
        BanffMarathonRunner philipWinne = new BanffMarathonRunner("Philip", "Winne", "Box 2222", 445, 9);
        BanffMarathonRunner alexTrebok = new BanffMarathonRunner("Alex", "123 Street", "Trebok", 275, 3);
        BanffMarathonRunner emmaPivoto = new BanffMarathonRunner("Emma", "123 Street", "Pivoto", 275, 4);
        BanffMarathonRunner johnLenthen = new BanffMarathonRunner("John", "Lenthen", "Box 2222", 243, 1);
        BanffMarathonRunner jamesLean = new BanffMarathonRunner("James", "123 Street", "Lean", 334, 1);
        BanffMarathonRunner janeOstin = new BanffMarathonRunner("Jane", "Ostin", "Box 2222", 412, 1);
        BanffMarathonRunner emilyCar = new BanffMarathonRunner("Emily", "Car", "Box 2222", 393, 4);

        BanffMarathonRunner[] runners = {elenaBrandon,thomasMolson,hamiltonWinn,suzieSarandin,philipWinne,
           alexTrebok,emmaPivoto,johnLenthen,jamesLean,janeOstin,emilyCar};

        BanffMarathonRunner[] fastestRunner = BanffMarathonRunner.getFastestRunner(runners[0]);

        System.out.println(fastestRunner[0]);
  }        

public static BanffMarathonRunner getFastestRunner(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners){

       int fastest;
       int currentFastest = runners[0].getTime();
       int nextTest;

       for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++){
         if (currentFastest == runners[2].getTime());{  
          // just trying to get it to  return the third runner no matter for testing

            BanffMarathonRunner fastestRunner = runners[i];
            return fastestRunner;
          }        
       }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: 1. BanffMarathonRunner.getFastestRunner(runners[0]); - you should pass the whole array. 2. sorting is not the best way to find the fastest runner. It is just enought to iterate thought the whole array finding the min value of time (search for example finding min value in array in java)

Comment: Do you need all the runners or just a subset of them? It's rather hard to answer this as we cannot decide on what function(s) your own app will need. Although try to make your decision on  easiest to implement versus most needed.

Comment: I probably didn't provide enough information, I'm still fairly new at this.  Getting back a single runner is adequate for what I'm needing.  The answer provided by Keith below really helped.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest harnessing the Java Collections API, and implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface in `BanffMarathonRunner`. This simply which requires you to implement the `compareTo()` function:

```
public int compareTo(BanffMarathonRunner otherRunner) {
    return Integer.compare(this.getTime(), otherRunner.getTime());
}
```

In your calling code, put the runners into a `List` and then just call `Collections.sort()`. Since you already started with an `array[]` of runners, you can use `Arrays.asList(runners)`.

If you're not happy with setting the `compareTo()` function within the runners (because hey, you might want to sort them by last name later), you can always use [`sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html), and stick whatever sorting behavior you want into there. In your case, the second argument would be :

```
new Comparator<BanffMarathonRunner >() {
  public int compare(BanffMarathonRunner a, BanffMarathonRunner b) {
    return a.getTime().compareTo(b.getTime());
  }});
```

I will caveat that, like others have said, you don't necessarily need to sort the list, since you're only looking to find the lowest time.

Comment: Thank you for this.   I'll have to keep researching the Comparable interface.  I find it very confusing to get, but I know I'm close to getting it :)

Comment: Sure thing. Just think of it as a way for an object to know how to compare itself to another object of the same class. By itself, it's clearly a two object case (e.g. "Did I run faster, slower, or the same pace as you")? But coupled with the power of an API like Collections we can use an efficient sorting algorithm (in this case, _mergesort_) to take an array and sort it by its _natural order_... or however you feel like the sorting logic. Heck, you could add eye color and sort that way so long as  compareTo() has a means to evaluates the colors. Say, ROYGBIV spectrum where R > O > Y... :)

Answer (score 1):

The comparator+sort solutions from the other answers will give you the added benefit of having all the runners in order.

If you only care about the fastest one, you just need to iterate through the array and keep the fastest runner found so far. In the end, you will have the fastest runner of the whole array.

```
public static BanffMarathonRunner getFastestRunner(BanffMarathonRunner[] runners){

    BanffMarathonRunner currentFastest = runners[0];

    for (BanffMarathonRunner runner : runners){
        if (runner.getTime() < currentFastest.getTime()) {
            currentFastest = runner;
        }
    }

    return currentFastest;
}
```

Then you just call it:

```
BanffMarathonRunner fastestRunner = getFastestRunner(runners);
```

On a side note - if you want to call `System.out.println(fastestRunner);`, you should override `toString()` method in the `BanffMarathonRunner` class to specify what exactly should be printed for each runner.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped me understand a few things I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the `Comparable` interface and sort the array (with `Arrays.sort`. The fastest runner is after sort the first object in the array.

But you should consider the case where more than one runners have the same fastest time. So you should return an array with the first items with the same time (`getFastestRunners()`)

Comment: Plus 1 for the unrealistic but technically correct concern about a tie in a marathon :)